# move sequence of files into sequence of directories in same path

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Hi i came across an issue,

So i have 500 CSV files with generic name like file_1.csv file_2.csv ..... file_500.csv and i have 500 empty directories that i created in same location with names like directory_1 directory_2 .... directory_500. All the 500 files and 500 directories are in the same location, i want to move each file into each directory of their matching sequence, something like this,

move file_1.csv to directory_1
move file_2.csv to directory_2
move file_3.csv to directory_3
.
.
.
move file_500.csv to directory_500

So, how do i do it? can someone let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..500}
do
  mv file_${i}.csv directory_${i}/
done
```